# Invalid index to scalar variable. How to fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

So, I checked other questions and answers about this and I didn't understand the reason, could you please help me with this, please

I'm learning linear regression and I implemented the code for Linear Regression with two variables.
This implementation should predict the sum of two numbers but it's giving an error

Implemented code here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]])
y = np.array([2,3,5,7,9,11])

#hypothesis
def hypothesis(theta, x):
    return theta[0] + theta[1]*x[0] + theta[2]*x[1]

#cost function J(t0, t1, t2)
def cost(theta, x, y):
    m = x.shape[0]
    error = 0
    for i in range(m):
        d = x[i]
        hx = hypothesis(theta, d)
        error = error + (hx - y[i])**2
    return error

#differentiation of cost function
def diffGradient(theta, x, y):
    grad = np.zeros((3,))
    m = x.shape[0]
    for i in range(m):
        hx = hypothesis(theta, x)
        grad[0] = grad[0] + (hx - y[i])
        grad[1] = grad[1] + (hx - y[i])*x[0]
        grad[2] = grad[2] + (hx - y[i])*x[1]
    return 0

#gradient descent funtion
def gradientDescent(x, y, learning_rate = 0.001):
    theta = [-2.0,0.0,1.0]
    iter = 100
    error_list = []
    theta_list = []
    for i in range(iter):
        d = x[i]
        grad = diffGradient(theta, d, y)
        e = cost(theta, d, y)
        error_list.append(e)
        theta_list.append((theta[0],theta[1],theta[2]))
        #simultaneous update
        theta[0] = theta[0] - learning_rate*grad[0]
        theta[1] = theta[1] - learning_rate*grad[1]
        theta[2] = theta[2] - learning_rate*grad[2]
    return theta, theta_list, error_list

final_theta, theta_list, error_list = gradientDescent(x,y)
```

After the above line, I'm getting this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-bda7687d0af9> in <module>
----> 1 final_theta, theta_list, error_list = gradientDescent(x,y)

<ipython-input-55-033133fbfbd5> in gradientDescent(x, y, learning_rate)
      8         d = x[i]
      9         grad = diffGradient(theta, d, y)
---> 10         e = cost(theta, d, y)
     11         error_list.append(e)
     12         theta_list.append((theta[0],theta[1],theta[2]))

<ipython-input-41-6a07f4b81c9c> in cost(theta, x, y)
      5     for i in range(m):
      6         d = x[i]
----> 7         hx = hypothesis(theta, d)
      8         error = error + (hx - y[i])**2
      9     return error

<ipython-input-27-43ce9d7c567b> in hypothesis(theta, x)
      1 #hypothesis
      2 def hypothesis(theta, x):
----> 3     return theta[0] + theta[1]*x[0] + theta[2]*x[1]

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Inside `cost`, `d` is a scalar (a single int), which is passed onto `hypothesis` as `x`. Now if you index a scalar (i.e. `np.array([1])[0][0]`), you get that error ;)

Comment: @Chris could you please tell me how to pass in that x more elaborately. I'm new to numpy

Comment: also if I do this ```d = x[0]``` and then ```print(d[0])``` it is working fine. why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the `x` that you pass to

```
gradientDescent(x,y)
```

Look at the traceback and try to figure out what variable has the problem - the problem is that you can't index a scalar, a number.  It has to be a list or array. Trace the problem variable back up through your code.

In the traceback:

- in the problem line you use `x[0]` and `x[1]`. What's `x` at this point?
- In the calling function it's `d`, which is set with `d = x[i]`
- In `gradientDescent` the passed variable is again called `d`, and set as `d = x[i]`

So you have 3 levels of indexing.  Does the original `x` support that?

You have to understand the problem before you try a fix.